# Natural join in SQL

Tags: sql

Tables:

```
Ships (shipName, shipType, launchDate)
Battles (battleName, battleDate)
Outcomes (shipName, battleName, result)
```

Write a SQL query that returns the names of the ships that were damaged in a naval battle, and later participated in a different kind.

Answer:

```
 select 
     o1.shipName
 from 
     (Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1)
 natural join
    (Battles b2 natural join Outcomes o2)
 where 
    o1.result = ’damaged’
    and b2.battleDate > b1.battleDate;
```

Can explain why this answer works?

When we do natural join then we join on attributes with same names?

Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1 In this one the only attribute that both have in common is battleName.

But in (Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1)

```
natural join
(Battles b2 natural join Outcomes o2)
```

all the attributes are common how does natural join work now?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it actually work as expected?

Comment: I understand your concern, but as @ypercube mentioned did you give it a try or is the expected result theory? I'm also in doubt about that...

Comment: No 
Shoudn't it be like this 
 select o1.shipName
    from (Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1)
      join
    (Battles b2 natural join Outcomes o2)
    where o1.result = ’damaged’
    and b2.battleDate > b1.battleDate;

Comment: The query as you have it (3 natural joins and a `where b2.battleDate > b1.battleDate`) is guaranteed to return 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NATURAL JOIN consists of joining tables considering their common column names.
The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) explains it in this way:

> The NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN of two tables is defined to be semantically
>   equivalent to an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN with a USING clause that
>   names all columns that exist in both tables.

The query works, because, using a NATURAL JOIN between `Battles b1` and `Outcomes o1`, there's the common column `battleName`, otherwise, without any common column, you won't get any useful result (an unexpected result).
Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=6/cafba/1#!2/ec9baf/1/0).

> But in (Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1) natural join (Battles b2
>   natural join Outcomes o2) alla the attributes are common how does
>   natural join work now?

The NATURAL JOIN works exactly like the first NATURAL JOIN, it considers the common columns. The query displays the result joining the two tables together more than once to consider the different battle dates of the respective rows.

Comment: IN the last one when all the attributes have same name natural join will only give us tuples that have same value in both tables.
if we have tupples  (war1,ship1,damage,2001) and  (war1,ship1,damage,2003)  in the (Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1) and same tupple in the other natural join then 
final result will be (war1,ship1,damage,2001) and (war1,ship1,damage,2003) we wont get (war1,ship1,damage,2001,2003) or (war1,ship1,damage,2001,2001) or (war1,ship1,damage,2003,2001)

Comment: @user2975699 Yes. If the columns don't match you'll get all the rows without any join and all the columns of both tables will be shown, because there's no match. Did you have a look at the fiddle I posted?

Comment: we wont get tuples like (war1,ship1,damage,2003,2001)

Comment: Yes i saw it. 
Our table only has BATTLENAME BATTLEDATE SHIPNAME RESULT 
as attributes. how can we then check b2.BattleDate and b1.Battledate these two attribute arent even in the table that is created from natural join.

Comment: @user2975699 Indeed, no. You'll not get rows like that (even because there's no other column with a date, except `battleDate` column of `outcomes` table).

Comment: how can we then check b2.BattleDate and b1.Battledate these two attribute aren't even in the table that is created by natural join.

Comment: @user2975699 Now I don't understand you, sorry! Play with the SQL Fiddle, you'll notice that just one column named `battleDate` will be part of the result table.

Comment: How can we have a where b2.battleDate > b1.battleDate) with this condition when our table only has one battleDate(I am referring to the table that was crated in from clause from all natural joins).

Answer (score 0):

Natural join works when you have column with this same name. You can using natural join and join..using - is this same. In You example column "battleName" well-suited for this

Comment: in the answer there are three natural join

Comment: Yes, but you using natural join beetwen battles and outcomes with three join. Part of the common is this same :)

Comment: natural join between battles and outcomes only has battleName in common.

Comment: this  (Battles b1 natural join Outcomes o1) natural join (Battles b2 natural join Outcomes o2) one has everything in common.